# ImageMagick commands are not working from JAVA code in OSX

Tags: java, macos, command-line, terminal, imagemagick

ImageMagick commands are not working from JAVA code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("compare /Users/labuser/Downloads/test.jpg /Users/labuser/Downloads/test1.jpg /Users/labuser/Downloads/differnce.jpg");
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "compare": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
```

When i tried from Terminal it works fine and produced output file in specified path.
I have verified for echo $PATH and it set to be

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin
```

Anyone please suggest me for should i need to add something to work these command from Terminal?
For other commands it working fine from terminal and error only with imageMagick commands

Comment: As `exec` know's nothing about your shell's `$PATH`, you may want to use the full path from `which compare`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ trashgod

Its working while specifying the full path to ImageBrick API's like

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/opt/ImageMagick/bin/compare /Users/labuser/Downloads/test.jpg /Users/labuser/Downloads/test1.jpg /Users/labuser/Downloads/diff.jpg");
```